# Django rest api csv to json

Tags: json, django, api, rest, csv

I would like to create a django rest api that receives a csv file and then response the file in a json format. How do I achieve this without using models and anything related with databases? I don't want to use a database because it's assumed that the csv files will have different structure every time

This is my first django project and I've seen lots of tutorials, even I did the first tutorial from django website but I can't understand how to do this task without the database.
Thanks!

Comment: You do not a need a model. Just a HTML page with an `<input/>` tag where you will upload the file and send to a Django view where you will read and transform the data, DRF is not even necessary for that task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you have not tried anything on your own Here is how you can do it

`views.py`

```
 from rest_franework.generics import CreateAPIView
    class ReadCSVView(CreateAPIView):
        # permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        serializer_class = ReadCSVSerializer
        queryset = ''
    
        def perform_create(self, serializer):
            file = serializer.validated_data['file']
            decoded_file = file.read().decode()
            io_string = io.StringIO(decoded_file)
            reader = csv.reader(io_string)
            next(reader) # incase you want to skip first row else remove this 
            return reader
    
        def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            final_data = []
            for row in self.perform_create(serializer):
                    if row[0]=="jack":
                          #do your logic here
                        final_data.append(row)
            return Response(final_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

just create one serializers to read csv.
`serializers.py`

```
from rest_framework import serializers
class ReadCSVSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    file = serializers.FileField()
```

now go to your urls.py and call the view class this way

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("read-csv",views.ReadCSVView.as_view(),name="csv")]
```

hope this clarifies your doubt

Comment: One last question, what if would like to handle the csv data before the response, remove some information or something like that, the portion of code must be written on perfom_create function? Or I need to create new functions? Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: i have added condition to be checked inside `create` method  with if conditions 
ps:: you may accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to it to help future visitors.